# JavaScript weird replacing

Tags: javascript

I am working on a simple project that generates Facebook BBCode (or something like that) in images that you can use while chatting.

Here's my full code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function gear()
{
var textArea = document.getElementById("id");
var insertedText = theForm.theText.value;
var charChanger = insertedText.replace(/a/ig, "[[f9.cha]] ").replace(/b/gi, "[[f9.chb]] ").replace(/c/gi, "[[f9.chc]] ").replace(/d/gi, "[[f9.chd]] ").replace(/e/gi, "[[f9.che]] ").replace(/f/gi, "[[f9.chf]] ").replace(/g/gi, "[[f9.chg]] ").replace(/h/gi, "[[f9.chh]] ").replace(/i/gi, "[[f9.chi]] ").replace(/j/gi, "[[f9.chj]] ").replace(/k/gi, "[[f9.chk]] ").replace(/l/gi, "[[f9.chl]] ").replace(/m/gi, "[[f9.chm]] ").replace(/n/gi, "[[f9.chn]] ").replace(/o/gi, "[[f9.cho]] ").replace(/p/gi, "[[f9.chp]] ").replace(/q/gi, "[[f9.chq]] ").replace(/r/gi, "[[f9.chr]] ").replace(/s/gi, "[[f9.chs]] ").replace(/t/gi, "[[f9.cht]] ").replace(/u/gi, "[[f9.chu]] ").replace(/v/gi, "[[f9.chv]] ").replace(/w/gi, "[[f9.chw]] ").replace(/x/gi, "[[f9.chx]] ").replace(/y/gi, "[[f9.chy]] ").replace(/z/gi, "[[f9.chz]] ");

textArea.innerHTML = charChanger;
}
</script>
<div align="center"><form name="theForm">
<textarea rows="5" name="theText" cols="120" onkeyup="gear();"></textarea>
<br>
<textarea readonly id="id" rows="20" cols="120"></textarea>
</form></div>
</body>
</html>
```

There are two `<textarea>`s. The first one is filled with strings, and the second replaces the strings by their replacement values.

And the function starts working after keyup event. It should work perfectly, but it returns some weird replacements starting from a character to g (the rest is working).
So is there a fix? Or another way, like replacing using arrays?

Comment: You're replacing the characters from `a` to `g`, so I would expect that result. Can you explain what the code is actually supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need 100 replacements, just one will do.

```
insertedText.replace(/([a-z])/gi, '[[f9.ch$1]]')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PRYWm/1/

Comment: problem solved! my codding is always messy, and regex?so cool!
thank you @elclanrs